# 'char **': invalid target type for dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

I have written the following code but when I compile it, the compiler gives me a bunch of errors about dynamic cast usage. How should I fix this issue? I have to implement the code with c++ feature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void draw(void* u, int w, int h) {
    char(*world)[w] = dynamic_cast<char**>(u);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            std::cout << world[y][x] ? "*" : " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int w = 30;
    int h = 30;
    char world[h][w];
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            world[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX / 10 ? 1 : 0;

    draw(world, w, h);
    return 0;
}
```

ٍErrors:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
message : see usage of 'w'
error C2680: 'char **': invalid target type for dynamic_cast
message : target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
message : see usage of 'h'
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
message : see usage of 'w'
error C3863: array type 'char [h][w]' is not assignable
> Blockquote
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the errors into the question, verbatim.

Comment: @Quentin I did it. Thanks.

Comment: dynamic_cast is used for casting of classes, especially polymorphic ones. You also can cast classes from/to void*, should be ok with dynamic_cast. If you need to convert to char** you should use static_cast.

Comment: @armagedescu you cannot ever `dynamic_cast` from `void*`.

Comment: @Quentin agree. But is possible to cast to void*.

Comment: @armagedescu yep!

Comment: `char world[h][w];` is not allowed in Standard C++. Nor is `char(*world)[w]`

Comment: FYI you also want  std::cout << (world[x][y] ? "*" : " "); so that the ternary evaluates first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expound upon above

The error comes from the fact that dynamic_cast needs a class type as per

`message : target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class`

You *can* pass a 2D array with a little more work on your part.  The idea is you want to treat the first dimension as an array of pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void draw(void *u, int w, int h) {
    char **world = static_cast<char **>(u);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            std::cout << world[x][y] ? "*" : " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int w = 30;
    int h = 30;
    char *world[h];
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        world[x] = new char[h];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            world[x][y] = rand() < RAND_MAX / 10 ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    draw(world, w, h);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant`

C can use variables as array sizes, but C++ cannot. Use `std::vector` for dynamic-size arrays, `std::array` for static-size arrays, and C-style arrays never.

> `error C2680: 'char **': invalid target type for dynamic_cast`

`dynamic_cast` is only valid for pointers and references to polymorphic class types, and neither `char**` nor `void *` qualify<sup>†</sup>. Just pass the correct type instead of `void *` and you won't need the cast at all.

<sup>†</sup> There is one exception for `dynamic_cast`ing *to* `void*`, but it does not apply here.

> `error C3863: array type 'char [h][w]' is not assignable`

Self-explanatory: C-style arrays cannot be copied or assigned to. Switching to `std::vector` will solve that as well.

Your code with these fixes applied:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

void draw(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const &world, int w, int h) {
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            // Also fixed the missing parentheses here
            std::cout << (world[y][x] ? "*" : " ");
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int w = 30;
    int h = 30;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> world(h, std::vector(w, '\0'));
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            world[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX / 10 ? 1 : 0;

    draw(world, w, h);
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ne7EzzZmYpPrVmxS)

Further improvements:

- `using World = std::vector<std::vector<char>>` to avoid repetition
- Replace the nested vectors with a matrix class if contiguous rows are preferable
- Use C++ `<random>` facilities instead of C's `rand()`